# Find Table Object Entity to get Current value of a Column before Updation in EntityFramework in Asp.Net Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

I`m new in MVC and want to know how to find a Table object entity using where just before updation.
My code is as follows:-

```
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PutEmployee(int id, Employee model)
{
    Employee emp = db.Employee.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
    if(emp!=null)
    {
        if(emp.ImagePath!=model.ImagePath)
        {
            //Code to move image
        }
        db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified; //THIS IS WHERE IT THROWS ERROR
        model.ImagePath = model.ImagePath.Replace("Temp/", "");
        db.Entry(model).Property(x => x.IsDeleted).IsModified = false;
        //Update changes using db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Code throws error on `db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;`

`Attaching an entity of type 'MyProject.Models.Employee' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate`

The purpose here is to check if Employee with Id exists and if it exists then check whether the current value of Employee.ImagePath is different from the model passed by the User.

Any help will be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to tell the DbContext that the state has changed, it will do that by itself if you change any property. So drop (both) lines where you are doing so.

Comment: But there's one more problem in removing these lines. i.e. My table entity contains 72 columns and I don't want to specify 72 columns with there new entry. Also it's not about 72 columns, it's simply about optimisation and the right method that can be used to achieve the solution. However I tried doing this before and a very thanks to ur answer #RobBos. If there's any another way to achieve the solution I would really help me

Comment: If you just update the 1 property of the entry, EF will mark the object as  `Modified`. After calling `SaveChanges()` the record will get updated in the database.